# AliPay sandbox environment (API for testing)

Tags: api, payment-gateway, sandbox, alipay

I am developing server side (back-end) app and I need integrate with AliPay:

- **Classical shopping API** https://doc.open.alipay.com/doc2/apiList?docType=4
- **Cross-border shopping API** http://aopsdkdownload.cn-hangzhou.alipay-pub.aliyun-inc.com/demo/alipayacquirecustoms.zip

But I can not find sandbox URL, so I can test my integration before going live to production.
**What is the testing API url (sandbox)?**

*Thanks a lot in advance!*

Comment: https://sandbox.alipaydev.com/sms/outMessageList.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using

```
var $gateway = "https://mapi.alipay.com/gateway.do?";
var $gatewayTest = "https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do?";
```

Comment: @FelixSFD thx for formatting, but could you please remove <br> then? I cannot edit answer anymore